# query_posts not working after wordpress 3.7 update

Tags: query-posts

I recently updated to wordpress 3.7 and all of a sudden my posts page stopped working . it shows nothing and opens up a blank page . there is small code on that page and it stopped working . It was using `query_posts` to get the posts but now a bank page shows up .

the code

```
    <? query_posts ('cat=-103&posts_per_page=1') ?>

 <? while (have_posts ()) { the_post ();  ?>

    <div class="reu-sec">

        <h2><a href="<? the_permalink() ?>"><? the_title (); ?><span class="sbttlmn"> &nbsp <?= get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'sub-title', true); ?></span></a></h2>

        <div class="desc">

            <? //the_content ('[More]'); ?>

            <div class="reu-prev1"><a href="<? the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?= get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'image', true); ?>"/></a></div>

            <div class="reu-prev2"><a href="<? the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?= get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'image2', true); ?>"/></a></div>

            <div class="reu-prev3"><a href="<? the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?= get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'image3', true); ?>"/></a></div>

        </div>

        <div style="clear: both"></div>

    </div>

<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `query_posts()`?

Comment: i found that only non login user are facing problem . the users who login are able to see the posts

Comment: Well, nothing in the code you've posted is specific to logged in vs. non-logged in users. You'll need to find and post the code related to logged in users.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `query_posts()` in your template file. Instead, you need to *filter the main query object*, via `pre_get_posts`.

The following function will exclude the specified category and change posts per page for the main blog posts index:

```
function wpse102566_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'category__not_in', array( '103' ) );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse102566_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: i found that only non login user are facing problem . the users who login are able to see the posts

Comment: You have a deeper problem if Chip's code didn't work and you are seeing different results for logged in/not logged in users.  Can you turn on debugging?

Comment: its like its going into a redirection loop when i open the posts page without login . and if i open that page after login . it works fine